# ASPxGridView Sorting event not firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, devexpress

I apologize if this may sound like an easy fix. I am very new at using VB.Net and DevExpress' library of gridviews and many other wonderful things so far. I'm trying to get more familiar with DevExpress and VB.Net in general. So far, I've been trying to get ASPxGridView with a sorted event to be triggered but it just never comes across the function I have below. It is getting the datatable on page load but it is not triggering and sorting event function I have on here. Let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Here is my front code using DevExpress' ASPxGridView code.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ID="gdrDataView" ClientInstanceName="gdrDataView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Styles-AlternatingRow-BackColor="#DDDDDD" OnCustomColumnSort="gdrDataView_CustomColumnSort">
   <Settings GridLines="None" />
   <SettingsPager Position="Top" Mode="ShowPager" PageSize="50"></SettingsPager>
   <Styles SelectedRow-ForeColor="Black" SelectedRow-BackColor="#ffdd99"></Styles>
   <SettingsBehavior AllowSelectByRowClick="true" AllowSelectSingleRowOnly="false" AllowSort="true" />
   <SettingsEditing BatchEditSettings-StartEditAction="Click" BatchEditSettings-ShowConfirmOnLosingChanges="true"></SettingsEditing>
   <Columns>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="ID" FieldName="ID" ReadOnly="true">
           <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></CellStyle>
       </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="EnterBy" FieldName="EnterBy"  ReadOnly="true"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="EnterDate" FieldName="EnterDate" ReadOnly="true"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Contact" FieldName="Contact" ReadOnly="true"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn Caption="Start" FieldName="Start" ReadOnly="true">
           <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="g"></PropertiesDateEdit>
       </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn Caption="End" FieldName="End" ReadOnly="true">
           <PropertiesDateEdit DisplayFormatString="g"></PropertiesDateEdit>
       </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Status" FieldName="Status" ReadOnly="true"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Type" FieldName="Type" ReadOnly="true"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
       <dx:GridViewDataColumn Caption="Description" FieldName="Description" ReadOnly="true"></dx:GridViewDataColumn>
   </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Here is my backend code in VB.

```
Protected Sub gdrDataView_CustomColumnSort(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As CustomColumnSortEventArgs)
    Dim grid As ASPxGridView = TryCast(sender, ASPxGridView)
    Dim test As New DataService.DataService
    Dim data As DataSet
    data = test.GetChanges(ddlType.SelectedValue, CheckDBNull(CType(dtStart.SelectedDate, DateTime), enumObjectType.DateType), CheckDBNull(CType(dtEnd.SelectedDate, DateTime), enumObjectType.DateType))
    grid.DataSource = data.Tables(0)
    grid.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure the "SortMode" property is set to "Custom":

   - [GridViewDataColumnSettings.SortMode Property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebGridViewDataColumnSettings_SortModetopic)
   - [ASPxGridView - Custom Sorting](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q307431)
2. If you are binding data at runtime, follow the documentation to ensure its properly implemented:

   - [How to: Bind the ASPxGridView to Data Created at Runtime](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3788)
   - [Why might paging (sorting, grouping, filtering) not work in the ASPxGridView?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18183)

Comment: I've also added the { SortMode = "Custom" } a couple of times throughout this gridview and it doesn't seem to work. My gridview data disappears whenever I click on a column header.

Comment: Updated answer. If the grid data is empty upon sorting then it's most likely related to data binding.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo in event name which should be **OnCustomColumnSort** instead of **onOnCustomColumnSort**.

```
<dx:ASPxGridView runat="server" ... OnCustomColumnSort="gdrDataView_CustomColumnSort">
```

Could you also ensure that **AutoEventWireup** is true inside ASPX?

```
<%@ Page ... AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked that part. However, the issue is still there.